# Error when running argument script from textbook

Tags: python, typeerror, traceback

I have a beginners coding class for Python. The book we are using is "Coding for Penetration Testers Building Better Tools". During out second chapter we started to create Python scripts and I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with this script I am supposed to retype from the book. See Below.

```
import httplib, sys


if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    sys.exit("Usage " + sys.argv[0] + " <hostname> <port>\n")

host = sys.argv[1]
port = sys.argv[2]

client = httplib.HTTPConnection(host,port)
client.request("GET","/")
resp = client.getresponse()
client.close()

if resp.status == 200:
    print host + " : OK"
    sys.exit()

print host + " : DOWN! (" + resp.status + " , " + resp.reason + ")"
```

After running the code I get an error on line 20 (the last print line) stating:

```
selmer@ubuntu:~$ python /home/selmer/Desktop/scripts/arguments.py google.com 80
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/selmer/Desktop/scripts/arguments.py", line 20, in <module>
    print host + " : DOWN! (" + resp.status + " , " + resp.reason + ")"
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

All code is being run in Ubuntu 14.04 in a VM with Konsole and created in Gedit. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the print line from:

```
print host + " : DOWN! (" + resp.status + " , " + resp.reason + ")"
```

with:

```
print '%s DOWN! (%d, %s)' % (host, resp.status, resp.reason)
```

The original line tries to append an int (`resp.status`) to strings, as the error message says.

Comment: That edit worked perfectly! Thank you so much, it seems weird this is the second section of code that I have come across that seems to be written wrong. The last one had if statements written incorrectly and it took me quite a while to get resolved. Regardless. Do you think you could explain why that worked? I like to learn from mistakes where I can :)

Comment: If you're building up a string using `+`, you must ensure each item is a `str`.  For example, `foo = "a" + "b" + "c"` is ok, but `bar = "a" + 1` is not.  You could correct the second by saying `bar = "a" + str(1)` (or in your case `str(resp.status)`.  But my preferred option is to use string formatting instead - using `%` markers to build a string up e.g. `%s ` for str and `%d` for int.  There's plenty of pages out there on how to use string formatting in Python - so it's worth having a read through a few examples.